# Dictionary Not Working Properly

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I have been utilizing dictionaries throughout my code, and they all work the way I want expect for this dictionary:

```
switchState["index"+("\(cellNumber)")] = cellNumber
```

This is inside a `for in` were `cellNumber` is one of the variables. The `cellNumber` represents a `UISwitch` a user turned on.

This dictionary continues to overwrite itself, I cannot figure out why. The `"index"+("\(cellNumber)")` should give the dictionary a new key to store the `cellNumber` correct?

I'm trying to store this into `NSUserDefaults` as an `NSDictionary` and swift makes me have a `String` for the key or it won't store it. So when I do store the Dictionary only one value exists. Can you see an issue with the above `Code` or is there another way to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Dictionaty<key,Value>
// subscript(key: Key) -> Value?
// key can be Int, Double, String .... any Type: Hashable
// value can be Any (any number, string, struct, enumeration .... class)

var dict: Dictionary<Int,Int> = [1:1]

//  key    value
dict[10] = 100
dict[1] = 64364
dict[76575] = 1

dict.forEach { (key, value) -> () in
    print("storage for key: \(key) has value: \(value)")
    /*
    storage for key: 76575 has value: 1
    storage for key: 1 has value: 64364
    storage for key: 10 has value: 100
    */
}

var dict2 = [1:"alfa",2:"beta",3:"game"] // [2: "beta", 3: "game", 1: "alfa"]

dict2.forEach { (key, value) -> () in
    print("storage for key: \(key) has value: \(value)")
    /*
    storage for key: 2 has value: beta
    storage for key: 3 has value: game
    storage for key: 1 has value: alfa
    */
}
let key = 2
dict2.updateValue("HELLO", forKey: key) // returns string "beta" (old stored value)
print("now the value for key \(key) has value:", dict2[key])
/*
now the value for key 2 has value: Optional("HELLO")

why Optional?
*/
print("the value for key \(-3) has value:", dict2[-3])
/*
the value for key -3 has value: nil

How to remove value?
*/
dict2.removeValueForKey(1)  // returns string "alfa" (old value)
dict2[1]                    // return nil, as expected
```

You must save the value of the switch as Bool for the key cellNumber as String

```
var dict: [String:Bool] = [:]
for i in 10...15 {
    let j = i % 3
    dict.updateValue(j == 0, forKey: "switch\(i)")
}
print(dict)
/*
["switch12": true, "switch13": false, "switch11": false, "switch14": false, "switch10": false, "switch15": true]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I know that a dicitionary can be most anything. But I was specifically talking about saving to `NSUserDefaults`. In Swift when you want to save a `NSDictionary` to `NSUserDefaults` it can only handle `[String : AnyObject?]`. Also I have multiple switches in the table that are all indexed differently. So if I can store the `index ie. cellNumber` and the state of the `switch` in the dictionary and then store it to `NSUserDefaults` that would solve my problem. I will try your last suggestion and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: you trouble is that you save (key,value) as (key,key) dict["\(key)"] = key. but you need to save it like dict["\(key"] = value as WhatEverYouNeed as valid for  NSUserDefaults.

Comment: So I'm saving it like this `switchState[("\(cellNumber)")] = true` but it still overwrites itself every time. I call `.count` on the dictionary to ensure it is copying properly but it is only size 1 every time. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I understand what I have to do now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code can be simplified to:

```
swiftchState["index\(cellNumber)"] = cellNumber
```

You should check that for every loop, the cellNumber value changes.

Comment: @Si_Te_Feng thanks for the simplification. I was wondering if you know why the Dictionary is overwriting itself every time? I know it is not copying properly because I try `switchState.count` and it always returns 1. Any thoughts.

Comment: Have you made sure cellNumber is different for every loop?

Comment: @Si_Te_Feng I did and it does. I figured out the problem thanks for the help.